# How to alter test object properties in KotlinTest via interceptTestCase

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I am trying to use the *interceptTestCase* method to set up properties for a test case in [KotlinTest](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md) as below:

```
class MyTest : ShouldSpec() {
    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var thing = 123

    override fun interceptTestCase(context: TestCaseContext, test: () -> Unit) {
        items.add("foo")
        thing = 456
        println("Before test ${items.size} and ${thing}")
        test()
        println("After test ${items.size} and ${thing}")
    }

    init {
        should("not work like this") {
            println("During test ${items.size} and ${thing}")
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I get is:

> Before test 1 and 456
>
> During test 0 and 123
>
> After test 1 and 456

So the changes I have made are not visible within the test case. How should I change a property prior to each test being executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should access the current spec via `TestCaseContext`. each test has its separated `Spec`, for example:

```
override fun interceptTestCase(context: TestCaseContext, test: () -> Unit) {
    //                v--- casting down to the special Spec here.
    with(context.spec as MyTest) {
    //^--- using with function to take the `receiver` in lambda body

        items.add("foo") // --
                         //   |<--- update the context.spec properties
        thing = 456      // --

        println("Before test ${items.size} and ${thing}")
        test()
        println("After test ${items.size} and ${thing}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works. So the instance in which 'interceptTestCase' is run is a different instance from that in which the test case actually runs?

Comment: @GarthGilmour yes. for a `Spec` it will create `N+1` `Spec`s. one for the definition, others for the tests.